# RS485 Pull-up, Pull-down and single termination resistor

Tags: rs485, pullup, pulldown, termination, modbus

Currently I use for Modbus RTU via RS485 with a [shielded cable](https://www.lappkabel.com/fileadmin/documents/technische_doku/datenblaetter/unitronic/DB2170213EN.pdf) length of about 5 meters and a bitrate of 19.200 bit/s. Wired are 680 Ohm pull-up (A->+5V) and pull-down (B->GND) resistors near to the master. The Pull-Up and Pull-Down resistors came into the installation, because we face frequent transmission problems (BIAS) only with termination resistors. I had not installed any termination resistors, because the transmission worked. Currently I am troubleshooting and rethink about the missing termination resistors.

In existing installations I can easily install one termination resistor (e.g. 120 Ohm). And only one near to the master (where pull resistors located) and not at both ends of the bus due to mechanical accessibility.

[image: Modbus curcuit]

My questions: Is the introduction of just one termination resistor at least better than zero termination resistors? Or does it make the bus situation even worse than without any? What are the correct values for one termination resistor (and for the sake of completeness two)?

Comment: It depends on the cable and the existing config of the 680 ohms resistors. If you have pull ups and pull downs on each of the A and B wires then you are terminating in 170 ohms effectively and you might need between 220 ohms and 300 ohm added across A and B at the ends of the cable.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for your response. I added the cable documentation. What do you mean with config? How do you calculate 170 Ohm effectively or 220 ohms and 300 ohm added across A and B?

Comment: Config=configuration i.e. the precise details of the pull ups and pull downs. The 170 ohm calculation was wrong and so sorry about that. If each of the A and B wires has an impedance of 680 ohms /2 then, the effective A-B termination is 680 ohm. To make that closer to ~120 ohms requires 150 ohms across A and B.

Comment: Without doing the math, I bet the 680 ohm pull up/pull downs are for fail safe protection - to put the inputs of the receiver into a known state if the cable is not connected or breaks.  Those values probably do that even with a typical 120 parallel termination across the lines at the destination.  Those values are way to high to provide any meaningful SI benifits.

Comment: Measure it! Put a scope probes across A and B in your installation and check the waveforms with and without the termination resistor.  I'm not a SI specialist in any way, but I would recommend to have at least one termination resistor than none according to my understanding of how reflections in the line works. 680 should work as a bias even with one termination resistor, they'll give you around 0.4V at A-B when the bus is in the idle state